# No gradients provided for any variable. Code was working 2 weeks back

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, google-colaboratory

I'm implementing a CNN + RNN model for image captioning using flickr8k dataset on google colab. Until a few weeks ago, this code was working just fine, but now it is throwing an error at `model.fit_generator()`. It says that

> No gradients provided for any variable

I tried checking the past versions of the file only to find that previously when the code was executing properly, the model was called `model_1` but now it is called `functional_1`. The generator seems to be producing inputs as requested by the model. I am fairly new to deep learning so I can't really figure out how the code stopped working out of nowhere.

**EDIT_1:** After I downgrade the tensorflow version to 2.2 from 2.3, the model name changes from Functional_1 to Model_1, but yet the code produces the same error. So maybe that wasn't the problem.

Link to drive with colab notebook and dataset (open to all): https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11ZbXrQK3YuVo76-4on4FPa236MfUdk8c?usp=sharing

Code excluding the preprocessing:

```
#create input-output sequence pairs from the image description.
#data generator, used by model.fit_generator()
def data_generator(descriptions, features, tokenizer, max_length):
    while 1:
        for key, description_list in descriptions.items():
            #retrieve photo features
            feature = features[key][0]
            input_image, input_sequence, output_word = create_sequences(tokenizer, max_length, description_list, feature)
            yield [[input_image, input_sequence], output_word]

def create_sequences(tokenizer, max_length, desc_list, feature):
        X1, X2, y = list(), list(), list()
        # walk through each description for the image
        for desc in desc_list:
            # encode the sequence
            seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([desc])[0]
            # split one sequence into multiple X,y pairs
            for i in range(1, len(seq)):
                # split into input and output pair
                in_seq, out_seq = seq[:i], seq[i]
                # pad input sequence
                in_seq = pad_sequences([in_seq], maxlen=max_length)[0]
                # encode output sequence
                out_seq = to_categorical([out_seq], num_classes=vocab_size)[0]
                # store
                X1.append(feature)
                X2.append(in_seq)
                y.append(out_seq)
        return np.array(X1), np.array(X2), np.array(y)
    #You can check the shape of the input and output for your model
    [a,b],c = next(data_generator(train_descriptions, features, tokenizer, max_length))
    a.shape, b.shape, c.shape
    #((47, 2048), (47, 32), (47, 7577))

from keras.utils import plot_model
# define the captioning model
def define_model(vocab_size, max_length):
    # features from the CNN model squeezed from 2048 to 256 nodes
    inputs1 = Input(shape=(2048,))
    fe1 = Dropout(0.5)(inputs1)
    fe2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(fe1)
    # LSTM sequence model
    inputs2 = Input(shape=(max_length,))
    se1 = Embedding(vocab_size, 256, mask_zero=True)(inputs2)
    se2 = Dropout(0.5)(se1)
    se3 = LSTM(256)(se2)
    # Merging both models
    decoder1 = add([fe2, se3])
    decoder2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(decoder1)
    outputs = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(decoder2)
    # tie it together [image, seq] [word]
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2], outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    # summarize model
    print(model.summary())
    plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True)
    return model

# train our model
print('Dataset: ', len(train_imgs))
print('Descriptions: train=', len(train_descriptions))
print('Photos: train=', len(train_features))
print('Vocabulary Size:', vocab_size)
print('Description Length: ', max_length)
model = define_model(vocab_size, max_length)
epochs = 10
steps = len(train_descriptions)
# making a directory models to save our models
os.mkdir("models")
for i in range(epochs):
    generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, tokenizer, max_length)
    model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch= steps, verbose=1)
    model.save("models/model_" + str(i) + ".h5")
```

Error generated:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:757 train_step
        self.trainable_variables)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:2737 _minimize
        trainable_variables))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:562 _aggregate_gradients
        filtered_grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:1271 _filter_grads
        ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['embedding/embeddings:0', 'dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'lstm/lstm_cell/kernel:0', 'lstm/lstm_cell/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm/lstm_cell/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0'].
```

Comment: Not a real solution, but you could roll back to tf 2.2 in google colab and try a rerun to see if the versioning is an issue.

Comment: I downgraded the version and now when I create the model, its named model_1 just like the previous version of the code, but the 'No gradient found' error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who met this same error on google colab, the quickest fix that worked for me was to downgrade both, TensorFlow and Keras down. The versions that worked for me were:

Tensorflow=2.2
Keras=2.3.1

I simply pip uninstall the previous version and installed the stated version using pip.